# How to zip a folder in node js application & after zip downloading start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, nodes

I tried with npm package `adm-zip 0.4.4` because the latest one `0.4.7` doesn't work, `adm-zip  0.4.4` works on Windows but not on Mac & Linux. Another problem is that I only want `zip_folder` to be zipped but it zipps the whole directory structure staring from `folder_1`. This is the code:

```
var zip = new admZip();

zip.addLocalFolder("./folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/**zip_folder**");

zip.writeZip("./folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/download_folder/zip_folder.zip");
```

All this happens on the server side. I have searched a lot and tried many npm packages to zip a folder or directory. Any suggestions or any other good approach to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver), which was very helpful when I was using it. First you need `create` an instance of the `archiver` as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');

var archive = archiver.create('zip', {});
var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/zip_folder.zip');
```

This way you tell the `archiver` to zip the files or folders based on the format you pass along with the method. In this case it's `zip`. In addition, we create a `writeStream` which will be piped to the `archiver` as its output. Also, we use the `directory` method to append a directory and its files, recursively, given its `dirpath`:

```
archive.pipe(output);

archive
  .directory(__dirname + '/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/download_folder/zip_folder')
  .finalize();
```

At the end, we need to `finalize` the instance which prevents further appending to the archive structure.

Another option is to use the `bulk` method like so:

```
archive.bulk([{ 
  expand: true, cwd: './folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/download_folder/zip_folder/', 
  src: ['**/*'] 
}]).finalize();
```

**Update 1**

A little explanation for the `[**/*] syntax`: This will recursively include all folders `**` and files `*`.

Comment: Hi thanks, It working but one issue is there,  it  archive.directory zip the whole directory structure  means when it zip its include all folders i.e. /folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/ I want only zip the last_folder  in the whole path. So what I do ????

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Hi thanks, It working but one issue is there, it archive.directory zip the whole directory structure means when it zip its include all folders i.e. /folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/ I want only zip the last_folder in the whole path. So what I do ????

Comment: In that case use the `bulk` method instead of the `directory`. Give it a try.

Comment: yes its working... thanks, Can you explain me src: ['**/*'] in bulk ? what its mean.

Comment: Quick FYI - the `bulk` option was [removed from `archiver` in version 2.0.0](https://archiverjs.com/docs/#changelog).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the system's zip function:

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
execFile('zip', ['-r', '-j', zipName, path], function(err, stdout) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('success');
});
```

Replace `zipName` and `path` with what you need.