# How to download zip folder from node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I have files inside one folder and i want to download the folder form node js server. I try some code but it doesn't work. I get some examples about downloading ([Downloading folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890726/zip-and-download-from-nodejs), [How to zip folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364066/how-to-zip-a-folder-in-node-js-application-after-zip-downloading-start) )folder but they doesn't work for me or i did't understand them.

```
I have folder like:
    Allfilefolder
        -file1.js
        - file2.js
        -file3.js
```

I can download each file using:

```
app.get("/files/downloads", function(req,res){ 
      const fs = require('fs');
    var filepath = './Allfilefolder/file1.js'; 
    res.download(filepath ); 
});
```

But i don't know how to download the folder. any help please?

Comment: You don't zip any file yet, don't you ?

Comment: @TGrif yes I didn't zip folder yet. I just want to download folder from node server. For this I think I should have to zip it first. But I don't know how to do it yet. I searched many times but I couldn't find useful things. Could you help me if you have done similar things before.

Comment: @TGrif  you don't have solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you already have a zip software installed and accessible from your app, one way to do it is to use Node.js *child_process*, this way you don't even have to use an external library.

Here is a basic example, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970368/5156280) concise and effective answer:

```
// requiring child_process native module
const child_process = require('child_process');

const folderpath = './Allfilefolder';

app.get("/files/downloads", (req, res) => {

  // we want to use a sync exec to prevent returning response
  // before the end of the compression process
  child_process.execSync(`zip -r archive *`, {
    cwd: folderpath
  });

  // zip archive of your folder is ready to download
  res.download(folderpath + '/archive.zip');
});
```

You could also have a look at the npm [repository](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:zip) for packages that will handle archiving file or directory more robustly.